# hinge2 type joints in URDF

Tags: ros, urdf, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've gotten familiar with the standalone gazebo project using .model and .world files to describe robots. Currently trying to figure out ROS and URDFs. It looks like the available joint types in URDF are limited to 1 axis rotations. Is there any way to implement a hinge2 type of joint (such as a steerable wheel) in URDF? It looks like the only way is to use two separate joints to do such a function. Am I missing something? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12299/hinge2-type-joints-in-urdf/) by [WW](https://answers.ros.org/users/1455/ww/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best (and only) way to describe more complex joints is to chain together multiple single degree-of-freedom joints with fixed links.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0